# Compiling cpp files in docker container failing when run directly but OK if using interactive container

Tags: docker

I've created a docker image with all the modules required for our build environment.  If I start a container in interactive mode, I can build fine.

```
docker run -v <host:container> -w my_working_dir -it my_image
$make -j16
```

But if I try to do this from a command line I get compile failures (well into the process)

```
docker run -v <host:container> -w my_working_dir my_image bash -c "make -j16"
```

Also if I run the container detached and use docker exec I also get compile failures (same point)

```
docker run -v <host:container> -t --detach --name star_trek my_image
docker exec star_trek bash -c "cd my_working_dir; make -j16"
```

Entering an interactive session with the detached container also seems seems to pass though I though I have seen this fail as well.

```
docker exec -it star_trek_d bash
$make -j16
```

This will be part of an automated build system so I need to be able run this without user intervention.

I'm not sure why these are behaving differently but I ran multiple combination and the only way I've been able to get a success build is through the interactive method above.  Other then the interactive system having more of a logged in user configuration, what is the difference between running interactive or passing on command line?

My preferred method would to be run the container detached so I can send several sequential commands as we have a complex build and test process but if I have to spin the container up each time I'm OK with that as this point because I really need to get this running like last week.

*Commands are pseudo-code and simplified to aid visibility and using bash -c because I'm needing to run a script for our test and therefore doing something like bash -c "my_script.sh; run_test"

UPDATE - We need custom paths for our build tools.  I believe this is not working except in the interactive session.  Our /etc/bashrc file is used to build the correct path and export it.  When I do a docker run I've tried running a script that does a "source /etc/bashrc", among other initialization things we need, before doing the make but this doesn't seem to work.  Note have to pipe in password as this needs to be run using sudo.  The other commands seem to work fine.

```
bash -c 'echo su_password | sudo -S /tmp/startup.sh; make -j16'
```

I've also tried to just set on command without success

```
bash -c 'export <path>; make -j16'
```

What is the best way to set the path in the container so installed applications can be found?  I don't want to hard code them in the dockerfile but will at this point if I must.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have this working.  As our path is very long I set it to a variable and was passing it in on the command line.  Seems this was causing issues.

```
export PATH=$PATH/...
vs
export PATH=$PATH:/...
```

Now I am just specifying the whole path each time and everything is working.

```
 bash -c 'export PATH=$PATH/<dir>/<program>/bin:/<dir>/<program>/bin:...; make -j16'
```